# Nuxt3 project deployment issue

Tags: aws-amplify, digital-ocean, vercel, netlify, nuxt3

I have tried to deploy my Nuxt3 project on different platforms such as Vercel, Amplify, Netlify, and digitalOcean and getting different issues on each platforms.
On Vercel and Netlify, some of the pages takes so much time to get loaded or even not getting loaded.
On Amplify, some of the components of pages are not getting reflected.
But on different platforms there is no same issue.
And on my local I am not getting any issue like that.

I have tried to upgrade the version of Nuxt to the latest version which was v3.10.2, but still having same issue.